# Find teacher monthly report based on upload question

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am working on a portal where teachers upload question on the database. I want to calculate a report which teacher how many questions upload on the current day and show monthly report.

**question table**
[image]

**I want Result**

[image]

**I tried code**

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar/dates table , if not are you open to creating one to assist in filling in dates where no uploads have occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2 functions here:
[DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and [LAST_DAY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_day/)

Your SQL will look like this

```
SELECT count(id) AS question_count, DATE(created_at) AS date 
FROM questions 
WHERE created_at > LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND created_at < LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND user_id = 45 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at) 
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Note in the second condition the **INTERVAL 1 DAY** is outside the **LAST_DAY** function

Comment: Thanks, its work, but I want null or o(zero) question_cout column if the teacher did not upload on that date.

Comment: This will complicate the query. I noticed that you tagged Laravel, you can do this part in the Laravel using a simple loop after getting the result from the database.